# Copying files inside Azure VM is terribly slow

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-virtual-machine

I have a B4MS Azure Virtual Machine running and I have downloaded over 300GB files to my C: (Premium SSD) drive and now I'm copying these files to another (D:)data drive I have attached which is Premium SSD. However, when copying these data to the D: drive, the speed of file transfer is only capped at 30Mbps as follows. Even I tried to copy files within the C: drive, which is again 30Mbps. Would anyone can advise for this reason?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Azure Documentation for B-Series VMs says itself that,

> The B-series VMs are ideal for workloads that do not need the full performance of the CPU continuously

[Azure B-Series VMs - Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/sizes-b-series-burstable)

A Standard B4ms VM has a Disk Throughput limit of 35MBps (for both cached and uncached disk storage), so it seems that 30MBps is a reasonable speed for your VMs.

You might have to switch to a higher-end config VM that can consistently provide full performance of the underlying hardware and not a "burstable" performance.